# Insertion of leaves to array

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, binary-tree

We want to write the keys of leaves into an array using inorder traversal. We got an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Could you please help me?

```
int [] leafToArray(){
        int size = getLeafCount();
        int [] arrLeaves = new int [size];
        leafToArray(root, arrLeaves, 0);
        return arrLeaves;
    }

    int leafToArray(Node n, int [] A, int filled){
        if (n == null) return filled;

        int lFilled = leafToArray(n.left, A, filled);

        if (n.left == null && n.right == null)
            A[lFilled] = n.key;

        int rFilled = leafToArray(n.right, A, lFilled + 1);
        return rFilled;
    }
```

Comment: Show you leafCount method.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you reserve, increase `filled`, also for non-leafs.

```
int leafToArray(Node n, int[] a, int filled){
    if (n == null) {
        return filled;
    }
    filled = leafToArray(n.left, a, filled);

    if (n.left == null && n.right == null) {
        a[filled] = n.key;
        ++filled;
    }
    return leafToArray(n.right, a, filled);
}
```

The problem is that the running index, `filled`, must be both input parameter and result. It can be done differently, but this is fine.

Do not introduce too many variables, they complicate things here.